# Zend Framework csrf session issue

Tags: zend-framework, session, frameworks, csrf, zend-form-element

My code was working fine and all of a sudden when I'm trying to add a cssrf element to the form this way:

`$this->addElement('hash', 'csrf', 'Category' . time());`

The following error occurs

`Fatal error:  Cannot return string offsets by reference in /usr/share/Zend/library/Zend/Session/Abstract.php on line 160
Stack trace:
  1. {main}() /Users/myname/Sites/Zend_Projects/myproject/public/index.php:0
  2. Zend_Application->run() /Users/myname/Sites/Zend_Projects/myproject/public/index.php:26
  3. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() /usr/share/Zend/library/Zend/Application.php:366
  4. Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() /usr/share/Zend/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php:97
  5. Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch() /usr/share/Zend/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php:954
  6. Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch() /usr/share/Zend/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:295
  7. Effigy_MaestroController->editAction() /usr/share/Zend/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php:513
  8. Zend_Form->__construct() /Users/myname/Sites/Zend_Projects/myproject/application/modules/effigy/controllers/MaestroController.php:109
  9. Application_Form_Extendible_Category->init() /usr/share/Zend/library/Zend/Form.php:240
 10. Zend_Form->addElement() /Users/myname/Sites/Zend_Projects/myproject/application/forms/Extendible/Category.php:100
 11. Zend_Form->createElement() /usr/share/Zend/library/Zend/Form.php:1040
 12. Zend_Form_Element_Hash->__construct() /usr/share/Zend/library/Zend/Form.php:1112
 13. Zend_Form_Element_Hash->initCsrfValidator() /usr/share/Zend/library/Zend/Form/Element/Hash.php:83
 14. Zend_Session_Namespace->__get() /usr/share/Zend/library/Zend/Session/Namespace.php:0
 15. Zend_Session_Abstract::_namespaceGet() /usr/share/Zend/library/Zend/Session/Namespace.php:287`

Why does this happen and what can be done about it?

Comment: Good article about ZF and CSRF http://plutov.by/post/zf_csrf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a comment on the [quick start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-form.html#comment-1268) I feel you too using a module and getting into the same issue . Quoting it for quick reference.

`But if you put the same same code in a module, it tries to create the session file iin the directory APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session" which doesn't exist by default so an exception is raised.`

```
$this->addElement('hash', 'csrf', array(
    'ignore' => true,
));
```

And I feel you can use this plugin http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/10/16/how-to-csrf-protect-all-your-forms/

> What it does ?

ZF controller plugin which automatically secures all your forms – neat, huh?